# aggregation in subqueries using Outer reference inside case. Getting Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, correlated-subquery

This is just small part of my complete query

I have some data where am calculating This Year and last year (a lot other things) values using aggregation and subquery.

Below is the working and simplest version of my query:

```
SELECT distinct 
       t1.country,
       t1.manufacturer,
       t1.category,
       t1.month, 
       t1.year,
(SELECT SUM(value) FROM data  ----- value is the column name which i want to aggregate 
    WHERE mar_short_desc = t1.mar_short_desc
    AND category = t1.category
    AND manufacturer = t1.manufacturer
    AND month = t1.month
    AND year = t1.year ----- This Is the only difference Filter
) AS Company_TY, 
(SELECT SUM(value) FROM data  
    WHERE mar_short_desc = t1.mar_short_desc
    AND category = t1.category
    AND manufacturer = t1.manufacturer
    AND month = t1.month
    AND year = t1.year -1  ----- This Is the only difference Filter
) AS Company_LY,
FROM data  t1
----- Other filters are here ignored for simplicity 
) a
```

I want to optimize it. So trying to merge both subqueries to one and using a 'case' statement to calculate the same values.

Here is the modified version:

```
SELECT distinct
       t1.country,
       t1.manufacturer,
       t1.category,
       t1.month, 
       t1.year,
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN year = t1.year THEN value END) AS Company_TY,
        SUM(CASE WHEN year = t1.year -1 THEN value END) AS company_LY 
FROM data
    WHERE mar_short_desc = t1.mar_short_desc
    AND category = t1.category
    AND manufacturer = t1.manufacturer
    AND month = t1.month
)
FROM data  t1
) a
```

> This giving me ERROR : "Multiple columns are specified in an
>   aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression
>   being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer
>   reference must be the only column referenced in the expression."

All i want to do is to make a frame of all common filters and then aggregate that result with the unique filter (reason: so i don't have to filter same thing again and again. its a big code and lots of data so, want to optimize)

Comment: MAX ans SUM are not the same thing. You could improve this question by adding sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: Is your second query really optimized? What if there are 15 years of data in the database? You'll potentially have to scan all 15 years just and throw away 13 of them.

Comment: @P.Salmon updated post its SUM() above also. And I want the result that i am getting from the first query. Its a simple Over + partion By + another filter where am getting last year same month value. To mention this is just a part of 8000 lines of query operating over 10gb of data and 20 columns.

Comment: It's quite strange to select `DISTINCT a, b` and then have a correlated subquery using the same columns. At least the first subquery seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn when i have 10 gb of data and i have to do these filters for each and every row and have to go through such sub queries 20 times (Dont have any other way ~ Or am unaware of learning phase) i think its better one time filter and calculate than 20 times doing the same. Any suggestions on how to go around this reference problem?

Comment: You can only return 1 value from a correlated sub query so the first query is the way to go. You may want to create a view and join to that but views don't have a good rep for performance.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel part of a 8000 rows of code and i got more unions to calculate data at different level. I have 20 columns where i want to group by till 4-5 columns then sum the value column dont want other columns in final table. ( *Can't use group by)

Comment: @P.Salmon thats another issue i see.

Comment: @P.Salmon I can use outer apply not an issue but still getting the same error message."Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference...."

Comment: There is no such thing as outer apply in mysql - is this question tagged properly?

Comment: @P.Salmon Changed tag to sql server

Answer (score 0):

For optimization, consider avoiding the correlated subqueries in `SELECT` and simply `JOIN` main table to derived tables. This should be more efficient as aggregation is run once and not for every row in outer query.

Below uses two derived tables due to the differing year match. While more verbose with added `GROUP BY` clauses, it should run better than correlated subqueries from first SQL code block. Even add indexes to the join fields for enhanced performance.

```
SELECT distinct
       t1.country,
       t1.manufacturer,
       t1.category,
       t1.month, 
       t1.year,
       sub1.Company_TY,
       sub2.Company_LY
FROM data  t1
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT mar_short_desc, category,  manufacturer, month, year,
           SUM(value) AS Company_TY
    FROM data 
    GROUP BY mar_short_desc, category, manufacturer, month, year
   ) sub1
ON sub1.mar_short_desc = t1.mar_short_desc
AND sub1.category = t1.category
AND sub1.manufacturer = t1.manufacturer
AND sub1.month = t1.month
AND sub1.year = t1.year

INNER JOIN
   (SELECT mar_short_desc, category,  manufacturer, month, year,
           SUM(value) AS Company_LY
    FROM data 
    GROUP BY mar_short_desc, category, manufacturer, month, year
   ) sub2
ON sub2.mar_short_desc = t1.mar_short_desc
AND sub2.category = t1.category
AND sub2.manufacturer = t1.manufacturer
AND sub2.month = t1.month
AND sub2.year = t1.year - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original example you have two columns being returned to the outer query by the inner one, it might work if you pop one out and leave the other in the subquery. I'm not sure how this will get on with the distinct clause you are using.

```
SELECT distinct
   t1.country,
   t1.manufacturer,
   t1.category,
   t1.month, 
   t1.year,
   SUM(CASE WHEN year = t1.year THEN value END) AS Company_TY,
   (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN year = t1.year -1 THEN value END) AS company_LY 
        FROM data
            WHERE mar_short_desc = t1.mar_short_desc
            AND category = t1.category
            AND manufacturer = t1.manufacturer
            AND month = t1.month
        )
FROM data  t1
) a
```

Try the query below too, it uses GROUP BY and derived tables which are both more efficient.

```
select Data1.country
 , Data1.manufacturer
 , Data1.category
 , Data1.month
 , Data1.year
 , Data1.Total
 , Data2.Total
from (SELECT t1.country,
             t1.manufacturer,
             t1.category,
             t1.month, 
             t1.year,
             SUM(value) 'Total'
        from data
        group by t1.country,
                 t1.manufacturer,
                 t1.category,
                 t1.month, 
                 t1.year) Data1
    inner join (SELECT country,
                       manufacturer,
                       category,
                       month, 
                       year,
                       SUM(value) 'Total'
                    from data
                    group by country,
                             manufacturer,
                             category,
                             month, 
                             year) Data2 on Data2.country = Data1.country
                                        and Data2.manufacturer = Data1.manufacturer
                                        and Data2.category = Data1.category
                                        and Data2.month = Data1.month
                                        and Data2.year = Data1.year -1
```